# Multiple Meidaplayer objects for playlist

Tags: android, performance, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an Android app in which the user can create a playlists of mp3 files. I am using `Mediaplayer` to control the playback of the mp3 files.

Which of the following is best to handle the playlist feature?

1. Create multiple instances of a `Mediaplayer`, store them in an array and iterate the array and call `prepareAsync()` on each `Mediaplayer` object. Then iterate the array and `start()` each object and upon completion `release()` the object.
2. Have one Mediaplayer instance and upon completion of the playback, `reset()` and change the `dataSource` of the object.

Comment: Would you like to create a playlist also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer, 2nd option looks fine to me, as there is no need to have multiple MediaPlayer instance instead its better to manage with single instance of MediaPlayer.

Currently, I am working on an application which plays list of videos one by one and for that I am using single VideoView and managing to play all the video just by resetting the datasource and that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how to create a playlist and add songs (mp3 files) into a playlist. Here is one link on Stackoverflow, [Android Create Playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182937/android-create-playlist)

If you still have questions, I may have better/other links on this matter.
Good luck.